# Add Uploaded File(s) to iTextSharp PDF New Page

Tags: c#, pdf, itext

I'm at the last step in completing a pdf generator. I am using iText sharp and i am able to stamp a base64 image with no problem thanks to help from StackOverflow.

My question is how would I iterate over posted files and add a new page with posted image files on it. Here is my current way of stamping an image... however, its coming from base64. I need to add uploaded images selected from my application to the pdf preferably while the stamper is opened. Just can't seem to make my code work.

I feel this is easy to iterate thru but can't get the logic. Please help:

```
        PdfContentByte pdfContentByte = stamper.GetOverContent(1);
        PdfContentByte pdfContentByte2 = stamper.GetOverContent(4);
        var image = iTextSharp.text.Image.GetInstance(
            Convert.FromBase64String(match.Groups["data"].Value)
        );
        image.SetAbsolutePosition(270, 90);
        image.ScaleToFit(250f, 100f);
        pdfContentByte.AddImage(image);
```

//stamping base64 image works perfect - now i need to stamp the uploaded images onto a new page in the same document before stamper closes.

```
        var imagepath = "//test//";
        HttpFileCollection uploadFilCol = HttpContext.Current.Request.Files;
        for (int i = 0; i < uploadFilCol.Count; i++)
        {
            HttpPostedFile file = uploadFilCol[i];

            using (FileStream fs = new FileStream(imagepath +  "Invoice-" +

            HttpContext.Current.Request.Form.Get("genUUID") + file, FileMode.Open))
            {
                HttpPostedFile file = uploadFilCol[i];

                pdfContentByte2.AddImage(file);

            }

        }
```

My posted files comes from input form on an html page

```
<input type="file" id="file" name="files[]" runat="server" multiple />
```

Comment: Are you adding the image(s) to: [1] existing page(s), or [2] need to insert a completely new (appended blank) page then add image(s) in the PDF? From your code snippets, looks like [1].

Comment: To the already existing pdf which is already open using Stamper.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The basic steps:

- Iterate over the `HttpFileCollection`.
- Read each `HttpPostedFile` into a byte array.
- Create iText `Image` with byte array in previous step.
- Set the image absolute position, and optionally scale as needed.
- Add image at specified page number with `GetOverContent()`

A quick snippet to get you started. **Not** tested, and assumes you have `PdfReader`, `Stream`, and `PdfStamper` setup, along with a working file upload:

```
HttpFileCollection uploadFilCol = HttpContext.Current.Request.Files;
for (int i = 0; i < uploadFilCol.Count; i++)
{
    HttpPostedFile postedFile = uploadFilCol[i];
    using (var br = new BinaryReader(postedFile.InputStream))
    {
        var imageBytes = br.ReadBytes(postedFile.ContentLength);
        var image = Image.GetInstance(imageBytes);

        // still not sure if you want to add a new blank page, but 
        // here's how
        //stamper.InsertPage(
        //    APPEND_NEW_PAGE_NUMBER, reader.GetPageSize(APPEND_NEW_PAGE_NUMBER - 1)
        //);

        // image absolute position
        image.SetAbsolutePosition(absoluteX, absoluteY);

        // scale image if needed
        // image.ScaleAbsolute(...);

        // PAGE_NUMBER => add image to specific page number
        stamper.GetOverContent(PAGE_NUMBER).AddImage(image);
    }
}
```